# @OneToMany MySQLIntegrityConstraintViolationException

Tags: json, hibernate, spring-boot

I have a @OneToMany Relationship between Role Class and User Class, and i have some problems in adding a new user, in the other hand i can add a new role without any problems. So i am not sure about the causes of the problem, because i did use the same method for another couple of classes and it works perfectly.

```
@Entity
public class User implements Serializable {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy=GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    @Column(name = "id", updatable = false, nullable = false)
    private Long id;
    @Column(name = "username", unique = true, nullable = false)
    private String username;
    @Column(name = "email", unique = true, nullable = false)
    private String email;   
    @Column(name = "password", nullable = false)
    private String password;
    @Column(name = "firstName", nullable = false)
    private String firstName;
    @Column(name = "lastName", nullable = false)
    private String lastName;
    @Column(name = "avatar", nullable = true)
    private String avatar;
    @ManyToOne
    @JoinColumn(name = "fk_role")
    @JsonBackReference
    private Role role;
}

@Entity
public class Role implements Serializable {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy=GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    @Column(name = "id", updatable = false, nullable = false)
    private Long id;    
    @Column(name = "roleName", unique = true, nullable = false)
    private String roleName;
    @OneToMany(cascade = {CascadeType.ALL}, mappedBy = "role", fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
    @JsonManagedReference
    private Set<User> users = new HashSet<User>();
}
```

This is the JSON request i make to create a new user:

```
{
    "username":"xxxx",
    "email":"xxxx@gmail.com",
    "password":"xxxx",
    "firstName":"xxxx",
    "lastName":"xxxx",
    "avatar":null,
    "role":{
        "id":3
    }
}
```

This is the JSON response for creating a new user:

```
{
    "timestamp": "2018-07-10T22:30:26.385+0000",
    "status": 500,
    "error": "Internal Server Error",
    "message": "could not execute statement; SQL [n/a]; constraint [null]; nested exception is org.hibernate.exception.ConstraintViolationException: could  not execute statement",
    "path": "/users"
}
```

This is the error i got in the back-end:

```
com.mysql.jdbc.exceptions.jdbc4.MySQLIntegrityConstraintViolationException: Column 'email' cannot be null
```

Can anyone help me to solve this problem please?

here is the API backend code :

```
//Create a new user
@RequestMapping(value="/users", method=RequestMethod.POST)
@ResponseBody
public User save(User u){
    return userRepository.save(u);
}
```

Comment: Can you post your API backend code? Seems like, your "email" attribute is becoming null along the way.

Comment: are your sure the `"role" : { "id" : 3 }` of your **JSON** request creates a valid **Role** object to persist?

Comment: Can you show your code where you populate User Entity

Comment: @SazzadurRahaman  i added the code you requested

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should add `@RequestBody` annotation before `User u`, like below:

```
public User save(@RequestBody User u){
   return userRepository.save(u);
}
```

Comment: ooops I didn't notice the missing @RequestBody , thank you !

Comment: Glad to help! :-)